# Use variables in gridOptions in ag-grid for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, variables, angular, filter, ag-grid

I'm working on a table in my Angular 2 application. I'm using ag-grid. this is my *gridOptions*

```
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{

        onGridReady: (() => {
            this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            this.gridOptions.onFilterModified = function () {
                console.log("Value Changed")
            }
        })
    }
```

This code works fine. If i change the value in the search field, i will get the text "Value Changed" in the console. I want to use a variable in the *OnFilterModified* function that is defined outside that function , but it doesn't work.

**console.log(this.)** after the dot i only get *onGridReady* function. That's it. How can i access other functions/variables in the *OnFilterModified* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an ag-grid or angular 2 quesion, but rather a javascript scoping one.

In the function (and I assume you're just using javascript here, not typescript) "this" isnt the out scope, but rather the functions, which isn't useful.

The easiest fix for you is to do the following:

```
    var that = this;
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        onGridReady: (() => {
            that.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            that.gridOptions.onFilterModified = function () {
                console.log(that.gridOptions)
                console.log("Value Changed")
            }
        })
    };
```

I'd check out this (there are many articles on this subject) for more information about JavaScript scope: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/ for a better understanding of the issue.